# Calling delete causes C++ program to freeze

Tags: c++, delete-operator

```
void FactorySystem::deleteObjectsToBeDeleted()
{
  //Delete all objects in the ObjectsToBeDeleted list 
  std::vector<unsigned>::iterator it = objectsToBeDeleted.begin();
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < objectsToBeDeleted.size(); i++)
  {
    GameObjectIDMapType::iterator it =  gameObjectIDMap.find(objectsToBeDeleted[i]);
    if(it == gameObjectIDMap.end())
      std::cout << "Bad memory or double deletion error!" << std::endl;
    else
    {
      //Delete it and remove its entry in the ID map
      std::cout << (it->second->GetID()) << std::endl;
      GameObject *object = it->second;
      delete object;
      gameObjectIDMap.erase(it);
    }
  }
  //All objects to be delete have been deleted
  objectsToBeDeleted.clear();
}
```

At the line where I call delete object, the program just hangs forever, and I can not figure out why.  I have googled this problem and it's like nobody has ever encountered this problem ever.  I must be doing something bad, but I have no idea what it could be.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

EDIT:

I was asked to show the destructor for GameObject, here it is:

```
GameObject::~GameObject()
{
  //Delete each component using the component's virtual destructor
  //takes care of all resources and memory.
  for( ComponentMapIt it = componentMap.begin();it!=componentMap.end();++it)
    delete it->second;
}
```

One other thing to not, I went into the disassembly and was able to step up until:

```
00488DA9  call        GameObject::`scalar deleting destructor' (044055Fh)
```

and then it just hangs, nothing else happens.

EDIT: Here was my rookie mistake.  For some reason I couldn't step into the delete call so I assumed it was in there, but putting a break point in it allowed me to go into it.  Thanks everyone, all your suggestions were very helpful.

```
void PhysicsManager::Unregister(RigidBody *Obj)
{
  std::list<RigidBody*>::iterator it = MasterList.begin();

  while(it != MasterList.end())
  {
    if(*it == Obj)
    {
      MasterList.erase(it);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: On what line is it freezing?

Comment: Shouldn't the error message be "Bad memory, cosmic ray bit flipping or double deletion error!" instead?

Comment: Hi, I posted the question, it is freezing at line 15, which is "delete object."

Comment: you're sure it hangs there, you e.g. checked with a debugger? in that case, show the destructor of `GameObject`

Comment: does `GameObject` own its `componentMap`'s entries? And where was `object` (the one to be `delete`d) created? Are you sure all those objects are on the heap?

Comment: You're possibly hitting something thats blocking further processing, such as an infinite loop in your destructor or some sort of locking mechanism. Nothing seems wrong with ~GameObject() itself, but maybe the destructor for the objects its deleting ( and any objects those objects destructors are deleting, etc etc ) are 'sticking'.

Comment: I believe they are all on the heap, I call new to make the GameObject, and then call new to create all components.  They are able to be used any time outside of the scope of their creation, so I'm pretty sure they are on the heap.

Comment: @Kindread, if this is the case, why can't I step to the destructor of the GameObject?  It won't step past delete GameObject.  I'm using Visual Studios as a debugger in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: My guess is that you're either trying to free memory you don't own, or you're trying to free memory you've already freed. Can you try to whittle your code down to a reproducible example that's reasonably short?

Comment: I assume GameObject is not a base class with derived types?

Comment: No, GameObject is not a base class.  It is a friend class to FactorySystem if that means anything.

Comment: Hey, I made an incredibly noobish mistake.  I need to learn how to use Visual Studio better.  Thanks for the suggestion of checking my components, that where it was.  Check my edit if you wanna laugh.

Comment: Oh well. Glad you solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
void PhysicsManager::Unregister(RigidBody *Obj)
{
  std::list<RigidBody*>::iterator it = MasterList.begin();

  while(it != MasterList.end())
  {
    if(*it == Obj)
    {
      MasterList.erase(it);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

**it** is constant and never changes: once the loop start and ***it != Obj** the loop continues forever